# How can I write f′ (x) with a prime?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I tried $f’(x)$ but it wouldn't show the ’. Should I install a package or is there a specific command for this?

Comment: By the way, the symbol is a prime.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Often, the solution is dependent on the packages that you are using, so better to specify that up front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type  `$f' (x)$`  or `$f^{\prime}(x)$`.

[image: f prime of x]

Comment: Just for the visitors: in math mode `'` is defined as `^{\prime} ` plus a few extra tricks, for example, `' '` is prime prime, so only n very special cases is there any need to manually use `\prime`

Answer (score 2):

In some editors, like TeXworks, but not only,   the typed ' (apostrophe or single quote) which is supposed to produce the prime in math mode,  is automatically replaced by the unicode character U+2019 (right single quotation mark ’) that breaks the TeX logic.

In such case you could either (1) disable this replacement (in TeXworks you can  edit the corresponding config file) or  (2) cancel it locally with Ctrl-Z .
A third alternative, if you use pdflatex and code in utf8, (and have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) you could use in the preamble :

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\ifmmode{^{\prime}}{\textquoteright}}
```

The drawback of the last approach is that the second (with `’’`) has a small spurious thinspace between the two `\prime`, hence the first approach seams the better one.

Comment: Good catch! Since `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` only makes sense when loading `inputenc` on PDFLaTeX, you might want to load `newunicodechar` and use the `\newunicodechar`  command instead.

Comment: @Davislor yes, my assumption about utf8 cas implicitly relative to pdflatex and inputenc, as the OP was not tagged with XeTeX or

Comment: Or another modern motor. But to my experience, the newunicodechar command fails silently if the char has already been defined.

Comment: Okay. Might be worth a mention in an engine-agnostic answer?

Comment: @Davislor. You are right, but think that the trick could be useful. I therefore efited my answer to be more explicit.